# TDD approach for developed source code

Tags: unit-testing, testing, tdd

I have been given a source code. I have to implement TDD approach to it.

How ever the general approach for TDD is:

1. Write the test.
2. Fail it.
3. Write the code.
4. Pass the test.
5. Refactor, if necessary.

    How should I add tests to such an existing source code?
   Suggestions for an ad-hoc approach for such a case, is welcome.
   Thanks

Comment: _Working Effectively with Legacy Code_ by Michael Feathers -- specifically, Chapter 2.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adding unit tests to legacy code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1541568/adding-unit-tests-to-legacy-code)

Comment: Also read up more on TDD, TDD requires test-first (code cannot be written before the test). So either you are trying to add (back-fill) tests to existing code OR you could be trying to follow TDD for all future changes to the source code? The answer will differ based on your situation. For the first, there is no easy answer - find areas you'd like to focus and increase test coverage. Come up with tests and implement. For the second, get the WELC book that Austin has recommended.

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget step 0: understand the requirements. What you can do is to discover the requirements, then write the test that demonstrates whether the requirement is satisfied. If it will pass, then great. If it doesn't, you've found a bug. Either way, you've added a regression test.

What you can't do is implement TDD (or any *development* practice) for code that's already been written: that boat has sailed. What you *can* do is enable future development on the codebase to benefit from test-driven development practices.

Comment: Thanks Graham. I am actually not convinced with your statement. Just making a test green doesnt rule out the possiblity that the test itself is buggy (specially in such cases).

Comment: Then what do you intend to do about that? Test the test code? If at some point you don't trust your own ability to write a simple test correctly, it'll be tests all the way down.

Comment: I dont disagree with your answer. However I am just not convinced.

Answer (score 0):

You could treat that code base as third party code and write some [learning tests](http://books.google.fr/books?id=goE1TL0u0dUC&pg=PA136&lpg=PA136&dq=%22learning%20test%22&source=bl&ots=I9xBqSezDf&sig=VWL3w32Z1lR5hH37-VvQ9srX_eM&hl=en&ei=1v7fSsCCFpWx4Qbnr8wX&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22Learning%20Test%22&f=false) for it. Learning tests will allow you to discover the code while building yourself a nice test suite for further developments should you have to modify the code later.

If the legacy code is small enough, you could do that until code coverage gets near a comfortable 90 or 100%.